# How to make a scrollable table with sticky headers

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a wide and tall table, and want the top row and column to always be visible.
`position: sticky` to the rescue!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sticky test</title>
    <style>
      th { padding: 20px 100px; background: #eeeeee; }
      td { padding: 50px 200px; background: #fafafa; }
      thead th:first-child { position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 3; }
      thead th:not(:first-child) { position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2; }
      tbody th { position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sticky test</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><th>a</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><th>b</th><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><th>c</th><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><th>d</th><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><th>e</th><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><th>f</th><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td></tr>
        <tr><th>g</th><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr>
        <tr><th>h</th><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td></tr>
        <tr><th>i</th><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td></tr>
        <tr><th>j</th><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>That's all, folks!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine.  But now the whole page is horizontally scrollable, and I'd rather have just the table be scrollable.

My attempt:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sticky test</title>
    <style>
      th { padding: 20px 100px; background: #eeeeee; }
      td { padding: 50px 200px; background: #fafafa; }
      thead th:first-child { position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 3; }
      thead th:not(:first-child) { position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2; }
      tbody th { position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
      .scrollable { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sticky test</h1>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><th>a</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><th>b</th><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
          <tr><th>c</th><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
          <tr><th>d</th><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
          <tr><th>e</th><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td></tr>
          <tr><th>f</th><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td></tr>
          <tr><th>g</th><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr>
          <tr><th>h</th><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td></tr>
          <tr><th>i</th><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td></tr>
          <tr><th>j</th><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <p>That's all, folks!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Indeed, the table is horizontally scrollable now.  But the stickiness of the top row is now broken.  (The left column is still properly sticky.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want like this [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header)

Comment: Basically, but that's not the issue.  The problem is that it doesn't play nice with a table in a container with `overflow-x: scroll;`.

Comment: .scrollable has no fxed height nor max-height set, it will expand without scrolling, only width is set here ;) here is what i mean https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vaNoEQ

Comment: G-Cyr: but that's not what I want.  I want the (vertical) stickiness to apply to the window, not the container, just like it does when you take `class="scrollable"` out.  (It's annoying that setting *horizontal* `overflow-x` and `width` changes how the *vertical* stickiness is applied.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [issue posted at W3C](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865)

It seems you can't make it work that way right now without also setting a max-height and

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to your table if that's an option.

If not, play around with something like this and see if that works for you:

```
<div class="">
  <table style="position: sticky; top: 0;">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>a</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><th>b</th><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
...
```

This is two tables and one of them sticky (the header part) until the end of the wrapping div is reached. You can then make both of them x-scrollable, hide the header scrollbar and link the scrolling to the bottom scrollbar with three lines of jQuery if you use that.

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pntu2a8j/).

Comment: Thanks for the info and tips.  It's annoying that setting a *horizontal* overflow and width changes what container the *vertical* stickiness applies to.  Your workarounds are helpful, but each do have their disadvantages.  The first requires a bit of a redesign and is especially tricky to get right on mobile, and the second one only really works with a fixed column width.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things are simpler these days (or always were?):

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

th { padding: 20px 50px; background: #eee; }
td { padding: 20px 50px; background: #fafafa; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th>Bar</th>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th>Bar</th>
      </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>a</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><th>b</th><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
      <tr><th>c</th><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
      <tr><th>d</th><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
      <tr><th>e</th><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td></tr>
      <tr><th>f</th><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td></tr>
      <tr><th>g</th><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr>
      <tr><th>h</th><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td></tr>
      <tr><th>i</th><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td></tr>
      <tr><th>j</th><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="height: 100vh">
  More scrolling space
</div>
```